# why my scrapy always tell me "TCP connection timed out"

Tags: scrapy

```
DEBUG: Retrying 
 (failed 2 times): TCP connection timed out: 110: Connection timed out.
```

ps:
System is ubuntu,
I can do this successfully:

wget http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Book/

the spider code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class DmozSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "dmoz"
    allowed_domains = ["dmoz.org"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/"]

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        sites = hxs.select('//ul/li')
        for site in sites:
            title = site.select('a/text()').extract()
            link = site.select('a/@href').extract()
            desc = site.select('text()').extract()
            print title, link, desc
```

Comment: can you post your spider code, scrapy settings and console output?

Comment: can you post your settings?

Comment: Is the code you posted an extract of the real spider code? your `start_urls` has either a 2nd URL that got stripped, or you have a syntax error. Try with `start_urls=["http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Python/Books/"]`

Comment: Did we ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: Question: suppose the problem is of the network, how can it be solved? I mean: I have a proxy in my company. I have set the proxy and now I can navigate on iternet (by browser). So I suppose Python should go out too.... or do I have to define the proxy someway by code?

Answer (score 3):

There's a problem within your network or a port is blocked.

Also check your settings for misconfiguration.

Comment: My system is ubuntu, it's port is opened default.So, now I really have no idea about the "TCP connection timed out: 110: Connection timed out."

Comment: I'm on Windows 7. In my case you are right: I have switcheed on another network and it worked.